# Running C processes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, ruby

I make a call just like this:

value = `./simulated_annealing`

Which is a C Object file, but Rails tells me it cannot find that file. I
put it in the same dir that the rest of the models files (since it's
called by one of those models), but I guess it should be in any other
place.

I've tried that outside Ruby and it works great.

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, when you say:

`./simulated_annealing`

you're explicitly saying: run file named `simulated_annealing` which is found in the current directory. That's what the `./` means. If the file's located elsewhere you need to provide the path to it, or add that path to the environment variable $PATH. So, you should replace that line with:

`/path/to/simulated_annealing`

where `/path/to` represents the actual path.

Comment: The problem is that I didn't knew the path. But I just print an "ls" commando and now I know :D thanks, it's solved!

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use an absolute path for running the program. For ex., 
you can create a directory "bin" under your rails application top level 
directory. Place your program under "bin" directory. Then you can 
execute the program something like:

```
cmd = "#{RAILS_ROOT}/bin/cbin arg1 arg2"
value = `#{cmd}`
```